# Is there some reason that the fact that $L^\infty$ is the dual space of $L^1$ is an important fact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Why is the fact that $L^\infty$ is the dual space of $L^1$ an important fact?

Comment: Key word: predual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a sigma-finite measure $\mu$, $L^\infty(\mu)$ is the dual of $L^1(\mu)$. However, it is not the case that $L^1$ is also the dual of $L^\infty$! See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space) for more details.

Comment: The OP probably meant $L^\infty(\Bbb{R})=L^1(\Bbb{R})'$

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $L^\infty$ is the dual space of $L^1$ implies that its closed unit ball is compact with respect to the weak-* topology. This is an important property of $L^\infty$.

The notion of weak-* convergence in $L^\infty$ can be illustrated by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma that states that, for all $f \in L^1({\bf R})$, we have the convergence
$$
\int_{\bf R} f(t) e^{int} dt \rightarrow 0 \hbox{ as } n \rightarrow \infty.
$$
This is the convergence of the sequence $\{e^{int}\}_n$ to zero in the weak-* topology of $L^\infty$. The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is certainly an important result in Fourier analysis and the compactness of the unit ball of $L^\infty$ may be used for example to prove generalizations of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: What you call "weak topology" should better be called weak$^\ast$ topology. It is not the weak topology in the sense of Banach spaces.

Comment: @MaoWao Indeed, corrected.